# How can this log class be improved so that it can be used across C# multiple projects?

Tags: c#, logging

I'm trying to determine if the following class is functional to use across multiple C# projects

The idea behind this class is that it auto-generates a log file if one has been edited or deleted while the program is running.

```
public static class Utility {
        #region INTERNAL LOG CLASS
        private static readonly object Lock = new object();

        public static string LogFileName { get; private set; }
        public static string LogFilePath { get; private set; }

        public static string GetDate() => DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        public static string GetTime() => DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

        public static void CreateLog(string filename, string filepath = null) {
            LogFileName = filename;
            var directoryInfo = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent;
            if (directoryInfo != null)
                LogFilePath = Path.Combine(filepath ?? directoryInfo.FullName, @"files\logs\", LogFileName);

            /* PUT APPROPRIATE WELCOME MESSAGE HERE */
            Log($"# NEW INSTANCE OF '{System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name}' RUNNING");
            Log($"# LOG CREATED (FILENAME: {LogFileName}, FILEPATH: {LogFilePath})");
        }

        public static void Log(string message, int format = 0) {
            lock (Lock) {
                try
                {
                    string logFormat = $"{GetDate()} @ {GetTime(),-8} |  >";

                    if (format == 0) { message = $"{message}{Environment.NewLine}"; }
                    else if (format == 1) { message = $"{logFormat} ### {message}{Environment.NewLine}"; }
                    else if (format == 2) { message = $"{logFormat} █ERROR█ {message}{Environment.NewLine}"; }
                    else if (format == 3) { message = $"{logFormat} --- {message} --- {Environment.NewLine}"; }
                    else { message = $"{logFormat} {message}{Environment.NewLine}"; }

                    LogToConsole(message);
                    AppendAllText(LogFilePath, message);
                } catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex) {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR"); throw ex; //Count not open / create file.
                }
            }
        }

        public static void LogToConsole(string message) {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }

        public static void OpenLog() {
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = LogFilePath, UseShellExecute = true });
        }

        public static void ClearLog() {
            WriteAllText(LogFilePath, string.Empty);
            Log("LOG CLEARED!", 1);
        }
        #endregion
```

Are there any issues that you can see that I should alter / consider changing?

Comment: Just a small point to mention - if you are using this across multiple projects you may want to consider using a standard timezone rather than DateTime.Now - If your projects are hosted in different environments or regions then your logging dates will vary per project, this can make reading logs a nightmare! Perhaps you could use UTC instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few suggestions...

I agree with [donners45](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4245136/donners45) in that try and use UTC where possible when storing dates, and convert to local time when you need to diplay them to a user.

If you want to make it portable, maybe avoid using MessageBox, as that might not be appropraite/availalbe in certain applications.

Perhaps use an Enum for the format instead of passing a magic number. Something like...

```
public enum LogFormat
    {
        Message,
        Hash,
        Error,
        Dash
    }

    public static void Log(string message, LogFormat format = LogFormat.Message)
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            try
            {
                string logFormat = $"{GetDate()} @ {GetTime(),-8} |  >";

                switch (format)
                {
                    case LogFormat.Message:
                        message = $"{message}{Environment.NewLine}";
                        break;

                    case LogFormat.Hash:
                        message = $"{logFormat} ### {message}{Environment.NewLine}";
                        break;

                    case LogFormat.Error:
                        message = $"{logFormat} ERROR {message}{Environment.NewLine}";
                        break;

                    case LogFormat.Dash:
                        message = $"{logFormat} --- {message} --- {Environment.NewLine}";
                        break;

                    default:
                        message = $"{logFormat} {message}{Environment.NewLine}";
                        break;

                }

                LogToConsole(message);
                File.AppendAllText(LogFilePath, message);
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
            {
                LogToConsole($"Error writing log: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Something else to consider is to make a logger interface and use that in your application.  You can write a file system implementation, but if you change your mind later, say to log in a database fr example, you can just write a new implementation and not have to change the code that uses it (just wherever the implementation is created).

For example...

```
public enum LogFormat
{
    Message,
    Hash,
    Error,
    Dash
}

public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message, LogFormat format);

    void LogToConsole(string message);

    void ClearLog();
}


public class FileSystemLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log(string message, LogFormat format)
    {
        // Your filesystem logging code here...
    }

    public void LogToConsole(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public void ClearLog()
    {
        // Your filesystem logging code here...
    }
}

public class DatabaseLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log(string message, LogFormat format)
    {
        // Your database logging code here...
    }

    public void LogToConsole(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public void ClearLog()
    {
        // Your database logging code here...
    }
}
```